# sem_init(...): What is the pshared parameter for?

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

In a graduate class, we've had to use semaphores to accomplish work with threads.

We were directed to use `sem_init` along with a bunch of other sem_* procedure but we were not given much information about the details of each of these sem_* methods.

The prototype (and header file) of `sem_init` is [the following](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sem_init.html):

```
#include <semaphore.h>

int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);
```

but I don't understand what the pshared value is used for. According to [opengroup.org](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sem_init.html):

> If the `pshared` argument has a non-zero
>   value, then the semaphore is shared
>   between processes; in this case, any
>   process that can access the semaphore
>   *`sem`* can use *`sem`* for performing
>   `sem_wait()`, `sem_trywait()`, `sem_post()`,
>   and `sem_destroy()` operations.

but I guess I don't understand the difference between say 1,2, 10, 25, 50000, etc. I think it is saying that if the value is 0 then the semaphore is not shared. (But then, what is the point?)

How do I appropriately use this `pshared` parameter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The GLIBC version of `sem_init` (what you get if you `man sem_init` on Linux) has this to say:

> "The  pshared  argument indicates whether this semaphore is to be
>   shared between the threads of a process, or between processes."

So `pshared` is a boolean value: in practice meaningful values passed to it are `false` (`0`) and `true` (`1`), though any non-0 value will be treated as true.  If you pass it 0 you will get a semaphore that can be accessed by other threads in the same process -- essentially an in-process lock.  You can use this as a mutex, or you can use it more generally for the resource-counting properties of a semaphore.  Arguably if pthreads supported a semaphore API you wouldn't need this feature of `sem_init`, but semaphores in Unix precede pthreads by quite a bit of time.

It would be better if the boolean was some kind of enumeration (e.g. `SEM_PROCESS_PRIVATE` vs `SEM_PROCESS_SHARED`), because then you wouldn't have had this question, but POSIX semaphores are a fairly old API as these things go.

Comment: It's not PC to call this version as belonging to GLIBC. It's POSIX.1-2001.

Comment: You can use `PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE` and `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` from `pthread.h`, they happen to have the right values (not a coincidence).

Answer (score 2):

I would say that there is no significant difference between the value s 1, 2, 5 and so on with respect to the `shared` parameter. Probably it is written that way because when the API was first created, C did not have boolean types.

Comment: So does that make it an outdated API?

Comment: I dunno - there is value sometimes in having the use of an older "tried and tested" API as well. You'd have to look at it from the point of view of things like efficiency and obvious security flaws to say if it was really outdated or not

Comment: Sneakyness: Yes and no.  No in that Pthreads, the more modern choice, doesn't seem to have a semaphore implementation, so for those cases where you want semaphores that's the API you'd need to use.  Yes, in that for most cases mutexes and conditions will do just fine in place of semaphores.

Answer (score 1):

The pshared argument indicates whether this semaphore is to be shared between the threads of a process, or between processes.

If pshared has the value 0, then the semaphore is shared between the threads of a process, and should be located at some address that is visible to all threads (e.g., a global variable, or a variable allocated dynamically on the heap).

If pshared is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes, and should be located in a region of shared memory (see shm_open(3), mmap(2), and shmget(2)). (Since a child created by fork(2) inherits its parent's memory mappings, it can also access the semaphore.) Any process that can access the shared memory region can operate on the semaphore using sem_post(3), sem_wait(3), etc.

Answer (score 0):

The pshared argument indicates whether this semaphore is to be shared between the threads of a process, or between processes.If pshared has the value 0, then the semaphore is shared between the threads of a process, and should be located at some address that is visible to all threads.If pshared is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared betweenprocesses, and should be located in a region of shared memory.

Comment: What is the additional value of this answer regarding to other answers here?