# IPC between TWO Virtual machine in XEN

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen, inter-process-communicat

Is is possible to do IPC between two virtual machine on top of same host using XEN ? **Can one program in one VM send a signal to other program in other VM ?** both VM are on top of same physical host.

Host os Fedora , guest OS also fedora, Xen version - 3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64

Any suggestion to communication between two program present in two different VM on top of same physical host?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

One possible reach is:

- Create an internal network between sender guest and receiver guest machine isolated from host network.
- Create a signal server using RPC. The server will be installed on the machine you want to send the signals. For sending signals you can make the server execute the function [`kill()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill). If you don't know how to RPC, you can have a look [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html).
- Implement the client using RPC.
- Install the client in the PC you want to send signals from.
- Create a infinite-loop process you can send signals to.
- Try send a signal remotely to check connections are working.

Comment: thank you SonicARG. I will try and let you know. As per my knowledge , kill is used to send signal , and that too in a single program where we can create multiple child process and send signal to each other. As per my understanding, even we can't send signal to two different program in a single host using kill. Am I right?

Comment: If you try to syncronize child processes (`fork`ed processes), then `kill()` is not the appropiate solution; in that case, you'll have to use semaphores in shared memory areas (have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847973/do-forked-child-processes-use-the-same-semaphore)).

Comment: About the limitation of `kill()`, the scope of application depends on the _pid_ value you specify to the function:  
  
 - `>  0`: Kill the process with PID value  
 - `== 0`: Kill the process group of the application  
 - `==-1`: Kill __all__ processes  
 - `< -1`: Kill process group with absoute value of specified (`-1093 -> group 1093`)

Comment: Even more, you can send many `kill()` to any processes you want to (is like a ordinary syscall), but be aware not to signal yourself beacuse it'd mean you're killing yourself!