# How to resume after a pause() call?

Tags: c, fork, semaphore

I need to resume after calling `pause()`, from what I read of the manual, it should resume after it receives a signal, but apparently is not working for me, also I'm using a semaphore to make sure that the program register the signal handler before I send the signal to resume it

```
void child(){
    fprintf(stdout,"Hello!\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    sem_t sem;
    sem_init(&sem,0,0);
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        signal(SIGCONT, child);
        sem_post(&sem);
        pause();
    } else {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        int status;
        waitpid(pid,&status, 0);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is not the actual program that I'm working on, but it has the structure of it.

What is happening is that the parent hangs at `waitpid()` and the child never leaves the `pause()` call, I know this because it never prints the message `"Hello!"`

Comment: If it's not working, what is happening?

Comment: I forgot to add that, thanks :)

Comment: Check the return value of `sem_init`. Maybe unnamed semaphores aren't supported on your system. I've had this happen to me on OS X machines. Edit: Also, shouldn't your second argument be non-zero? " If the pshared argument has a non-zero value, then the semaphore is shared between processes; in this case, any process that can access the semaphore sem can use sem for performing sem_wait(), sem_trywait(), sem_post(), and sem_destroy() operations."

Comment: From adding some print statements, it looks like it's not getting past the `sem_wait`, which agrees with what tangrs said.

Comment: I did 2 things, first I moved the semaphore to be a global variable, so it can be accessed and modified by the child thread, second I changed the value of pshared to 1 and check the value, and I see that is returning 0, so it is initializing correctly. Still don't know what I'm missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're actually falling victim to a failure in sharing the semaphore. If you follow the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6848235/57318) to put the semaphore in shared memory, then your program works fine:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

...

sem_t *sem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem), 
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
    -1, 0);
```

(and obviously replace the `&sem`s with `sem`)