# How to implement global POSIX semaphore to be used by two C programs?

Tags: c, semaphore

I have two C files: `a.c` (master) and `b.c` (follower).
I want to create a synchronization between master and follower using a semaphore.
According to what I have learnt I need to have a global POSIX semaphore to make this work.
How can I implement this in the `b.c` (follower) file using only the semaphores in `a.c` (master)?

**Semaphore implemented for `a.c` file (master):**

```c
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

sem_t x,y;
pthread_t tid;
pthread_t writerthreads[100],readerthreads[100];
int readercount = 0, writercount = 0;

void* reader(void* param)
{
    if (writercount > 0) {
        sem_wait(&x);
        readercount++;
        if (readercount == 1) {
            sem_wait(&y);
        }
        sem_post(&x);
        printf("%d reader is inside\n",readercount);

        //read all the files in the directory

        sleep(3);
        sem_wait(&x);
        readercount--;
        if (readercount == 0) {
            sem_post(&y);
        }
        sem_post(&x);
        printf("%d Reader is leaving\n",readercount+1);
    } else {
        printf("Nothing to view\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* writer(void* param)
{
    printf("Master is trying to upload\n");
    sem_wait(&y);
    printf("Master is uploading\n");

    //create file in a directory

    sem_post(&y);
    writercount++;
    printf("Master is leaving\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int a,i = 0,b;
    sem_init(&x,0,1);
    sem_init(&y,0,1);

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter 1 to View  / 2 to Upload / 3 to Exit:");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        if (b == 1) {
            pthread_create(&readerthreads[i],NULL,reader,NULL);
        } else if (b == 2) {
            pthread_create(&writerthreads[i],NULL,writer,NULL);
        } else {
            exit(0);
        }
        pthread_join(writerthreads[i],NULL);
        pthread_join(readerthreads[i],NULL);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Semaphore in the `b.c` file (follower):**

```c
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

sem_t x,y;
pthread_t tid;
pthread_t readerthreads[100];
int readercount = 0, writercount = 0;

void* reader(void* param)
{
    if (writercount > 0) {
        sem_wait(&x);
        readercount++;
        if (readercount == 1) {
            sem_wait(&y);
        }
        sem_post(&x);
        printf("%d Follower is inside\n",readercount);
        //read all the files in the directory
        sleep(3);
        sem_wait(&x);
        readercount--;
        if (readercount == 0) {
            sem_post(&y);
        }
        sem_post(&x);
        printf("%d Follower is leaving\n",readercount+1);
    } else {
        printf("Nothing to view\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int a,i = 0,b;
    sem_init(&x,0,1);
    sem_init(&y,0,1);

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter 1 to View  / 3 to Exit:");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        if (b == 1) {
            pthread_create(&readerthreads[i],NULL,reader,NULL);
        } else {
            exit(0);
        }
        pthread_join(readerthreads[i],NULL);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System-wide global variable / semaphore / mutex in C++/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338732/system-wide-global-variable-semaphore-mutex-in-c-linux)

Comment: Specifically, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html where it mentions that you must use `sem_open()` to create or open a named semaphore and that the name you give to the semaphore **must** start with `/`. Also make sure the name is unique, as other processes on the system also use global semaphores and you don't want your name to clash with others.

Comment: @NikosC., yes its useful, but can I see a sample implementation of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having two different process, you have to use **named semaphore**, like described here:

[Share POSIX semaphore among multiple processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205396/share-posix-semaphore-among-multiple-processes)

So your code can be edited like

`a.c`

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

sem_t *x,*y;
pthread_t tid;
pthread_t writerthreads[100],readerthreads[100];
int readercount = 0, writercount = 0;

void* reader(void* param)
{
    if (writercount > 0) {
        sem_wait(x);
        readercount++;
        if (readercount == 1) {
            sem_wait(y);
        }
        sem_post(x);
        printf("%d reader is inside\n",readercount);

        //read all the files in the directory

        sleep(3);
        sem_wait(x);
        readercount--;
        if (readercount == 0) {
            sem_post(y);
        }
        sem_post(x);
        printf("%d Reader is leaving\n",readercount+1);
    } else {
        printf("Nothing to view\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* writer(void* param)
{
    printf("Master is trying to upload\n");
    sem_wait(y);
    printf("Master is uploading\n");

    //create file in a directory

    sem_post(y);
    writercount++;
    printf("Master is leaving\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int a,i = 0,b;
    x = sem_open("/semaphore_x", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG  | S_IRWXO, 1);
    y = sem_open("/semaphore_y", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG  | S_IRWXO, 1);
    
    if( x == NULL || y == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open named semaphores\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter 1 to View  / 2 to Upload / 3 to Exit:");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        if (b == 1) {
            pthread_create(&readerthreads[i],NULL,reader,NULL);
        } else if (b == 2) {
            pthread_create(&writerthreads[i],NULL,writer,NULL);
        } else {
            sem_close(x);
            sem_close(y);
            sem_unlink("/semaphore_x");
            sem_unlink("/semaphore_y");
            exit(0);
        }
        pthread_join(writerthreads[i],NULL);
        pthread_join(readerthreads[i],NULL);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and `b.c`

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

sem_t *x,*y;
pthread_t tid;
pthread_t readerthreads[100];
int readercount = 0, writercount = 0;

void* reader(void* param)
{
    if (writercount > 0) {
        sem_wait(x);
        readercount++;
        if (readercount == 1) {
            sem_wait(y);
        }
        sem_post(x);
        printf("%d Follower is inside\n",readercount);
        //read all the files in the directory
        sleep(3);
        sem_wait(x);
        readercount--;
        if (readercount == 0) {
            sem_post(y);
        }
        sem_post(x);
        printf("%d Follower is leaving\n",readercount+1);
    } else {
        printf("Nothing to view\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int a,i = 0,b;
    x = sem_open("/semaphore_x", O_RDWR);
    y = sem_open("/semaphore_y", O_RDWR);

    if( x == NULL || y == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open named semaphores\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter 1 to View  / 3 to Exit:");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        if (b == 1) {
            pthread_create(&readerthreads[i],NULL,reader,NULL);
        } else {
            sem_close(x);
            sem_close(y);
            exit(0);
        }
        pthread_join(readerthreads[i],NULL);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: i read all the documentation is it possible for you to show me in one of my files how to implement as I have never done it before and its confusing to me since im a beginner. I want to know how to use after intializing the semphore name.

Comment: @CheckerPecker I edited the answer including modification on your source code. Please check the use of `writercount` in `b.c`, because nothing update its value.

Comment: thank you very much Im getting these errors: a.c:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `sem_open'
/usr/bin/ld: a.c:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `sem_open'
/usr/bin/ld: a.c:(.text+0x2ad): undefined reference to `sem_close'
/usr/bin/ld: a.c:(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `sem_close'
/usr/bin/ld: a.c:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `sem_unlink'
/usr/bin/ld: a.c:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `sem_unlink'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: how can I avoid them?

Comment: Did you link the thread lib? E.g.: `gcc a.c -lpthread -o a.exe`

Comment: yes i have linked

Comment: Are you in this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916881/sem-open-error-undefined-reference-to-sem-open-on-linux-ubuntu-10-10